# Select some field

Tags: python, database, python-3.x

I use Python 3.3 and database formatted as txt.

The database contains 6 columns,

```
id, date, r1, numbers, r2, numbers
```

like this:

```
id  date        r1  numbers         r2  numbers
1   25/03/2013  Ba  11 12 13 14 15  Da  33 44 55 66 77
2   26/03/2013  Ba  12 32 33 55 66  Da  22 11 14 17 23
3   27/03/2013  Ba  32 33 34 35 36  Da  37 38 39 40 41
```

The code that I have implemented it with Python is:

```
f = open('db.txt','r')

for line in f.read().split('\n'):

    print (line)
f.close()
```

I would like to print only the fourth column, including the header.

Is it possible?

Comment: Of course it is. Have you bothered defining the "fourth column" yet?

Comment: Are the columns tab delimited or just multiple spaces? Is installing a 3rd Party library an issue?

Comment: I use tab as delimiter and i not installet 3rd Party library.

Comment: This is the solution: 

for line in open("dbx.txt"):
    columns = line.split("\t")
    print (columns[3]) # indexing starts at zero

Answer (score 0):

*Solution moved from original poster's comment.*

The solution is:

```
for line in open("db.txt"):
    columns = line.split("\t")
    print (columns[3]) # indexing starts at zero
```